# Python 3.4 I am trying to send a post request to an anonymizing proxy zend2.com. But I just get their homepage as a response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests


zend2 = 'https://zend2.com/'

visitSite = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/'

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'

#zend2 data parameters
data_zend2 = {}
data_zend2['u'] = visitSite


#creating a session 
mySession = requests.Session()

req_01 = mySession.get(zend2, headers = headers)

post_01 = mySession.post(zend2, data = data_zend2,headers = headers)
```

The code is executing without errors its just sending me to the wrong page when I am trying to go to wikipedia. I have also tried using json.dumps() for the data but it didn't work.
If there are other libraries I can use I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I don't know if something so heavy is necessary, but you could try selenium with PhantomJS if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1):

Your post url and data were incorrect:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

# zend2 data parameters
data = {"u": "https://www.wikipedia.org/", "encodeURL": "on", "allowCookies": "on", "stripJS": "on",
              "stripObjects": "on"}


with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post("https://zend2.com/includes/process.php?action=update1", headers=headers, data=data)
    print(res.text)
```

If you look at the request in chrome or firebug, under the *other* tab you can see what happens:

[image]

If we use bs4 to parse a bit of the page, you can see we do get the wiki page content returned:

I

```
n [15]: import requests

In [16]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [17]: headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

In [18]: data = {"u": "https://www.wikipedia.org/", "encodeURL": "on", "allowCookies": "on", "stripJS": "on",
   ....:               "stripObjects": "on"}

In [19]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ....:         res = s.post("https://zend2.com/includes/process.php?action=update1", headers=headers, data=data)
   ....:         soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
   ....:         prin(soup.select_one("div.central-featured-lang.lang1"))
   ....:     
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
<a class="link-box" href="/open12.php?u=DQYIaIkz%2BRfJh%2B3hqurO3R7xaOuC&amp;b=29" title="English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia">
<strong>English</strong><br>
<em>The Free Encyclopedia</em><br>
<small>5 077 000+ articles</small>
</br></br></a>
</div>
```